# Doubly linked list implementation with dummy head and tail

Tags: c

I have the folowing:
typedef struct d_node d_node_t;

```
struct d_node
    {
        void *data;
        d_node_t *next;
        d_node_t *prev;
    };
typedef struct d_list d_list_t;
struct d_list
    {
        d_node_t head;
        d_node_t tail;
    };
```

How can I implement d_list_t *DListCreate(void) function?

Comment: Your definition of `struct d_list` seems wrong to me.  `head` and `tail` should be pointers shouldn't they?

Comment: If the requirement is that you have dummy objects at each end, then I'd guess that you just need to make head.next point to tail and tail.prev point to head.

Comment: It's really odd to have a fixed head and tail. As @cleblanc points out, these should be pointers as these change frequently.

Comment: The typedefs make sense if the non-pointer members of d_list are dummies and only their dummy.head.next points to actual head and dummy.tail.prev points to actual tail. Seems somewhat double-indirect, but should work. Probably dummy.tail.next = NULL and dummy.head.prev=NULL.

Comment: It's requirement, we'll use iterator to work with the list afterwards. But I have no Idea how to implement the required DListCreate

Comment: You just need to allocate memory for it and then fill in head.next and tail.prev. Set all the other pointers to NULL, or just calloc the memory in the first place.

Comment: @Yunnosch The signature is `d_list_t *DListCreate(void)`, so I assume it needs to be malloced?

Comment: @Rup That is a good point. Yes, the prototype implies to alloc and return, the alternative to use a global variable and return a pointer to it is of course ludicrous. Thanks for spotting.

Answer (score 2):

> I have no Idea how to implement the required DListCreate

Your `DListCreate()` function will probably create an empty list, right? That means no actual nodes, just the dummy head and tail nodes. So... ask yourself, what should `head->next` point to if there are no actual nodes? Likewise, what should `tail->prev` point to? All you need to do to create an empty list is to create one of your `d_list` structures, and then set the `head` and `tail` pointers appropriately.

Hint: the address of `myDList.tail` is `&(myDList.tail)`.

Answer (score 2):

```
d_list_t *DListCreate(void)
{
    d_list_t *myDList = (d_list_t*)malloc(sizeof(d_list_t));

    if (new_d_list == NULL)
    {
        return(NULL);

    }
   &(myDList.tail)->data = NULL;
   &(myDList.tail)->next = NULL;
   &(myDList.tail)->prev = &(myDList.head)

   &(myDList.head)->data = NULL;
   &(myDList.head)->next = &(myDList.tail);
   &(myDList.head)->prev = NULL;

   return(myDList);
}
```

Comment: Mostly looks good! I think you need `myDList->head` and `tail` though, since `myDList` is a pointer. You could then just use `myDList->head.data` etc. rather than dereferencing them and using `->` to access the members.

Comment: Oh, FWIW some posters here feel strongly that you [should not cast the result of malloc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc) (although I'm fine either way)

Comment: You've also mixed up `new_d_list` and `myDList` - you need to be consistent.

Comment: Yes, you're right.

Comment: @Ann Update your answer accordingly to help further readers.

Comment: A simpler way to say `&(myDList.tail)->next` is `myDList.tail.next`. You only need to take the address of `myDList.tail` in order to assign it to `head`'s `next` pointer. So, for example, `myDList.head.next = &(myDList.tail);`.